# Will XPS 13 2015 laptop support daisy chaining multiple monitors from a single display port?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, displayport

Will my XPS 13 2015 laptop support daisy chaining multiple monitors from a single display port output?

I understand that this will require display port v 1.2, but I've not so far been able to find out which version the XPS 13 2015 supports, and whether I will be able to run an additional 2 monitors from it.

The laptop is running Windows 8.

Comment: Since you have the hardware.  It should be a simple process to simple try and daisy chain the monitors.  What GPU do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

This Dell website on the XPS 13 2015 states the Video Card is "Intel (R) HD Graphics 5500". http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-13-9343-laptop/pd

The Intel website states that the Intel HD Graphics 5500 does use DisplayPort 1.2. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics

As noted in a comment, an alternate video card may allow a higher resolution.

Comment: Be careful:on laptops you don't have to check only the graphic adapter, but also the laptop himself (e.g. nvidia 330m supports 1440p, but when  on sony laptops hdmi output is limited to 1080p)